# Input::get() inside update query in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I use input data in a database update query?
Is it OK to use the following statement?

```
DB::update('update doctor set availability= 0 where doctorId= Input::get('doctorId');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Capture the input in a variable first, then concatenate it with the sql statement.**